# How to get the row index in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

I have created a table that has a column of registration number as primary key. I have created row_id using `row_number()` that is ordered by the primary key.

How can i search a registration number and get the row_id along with other information of that row?

Comment: The OP mentions *I have created row_id using row_number() that is ordered by the primary key* so the problem is not the same as the proposed duplicate link *"How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created the column `row_id` like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY registration_number)
```

then use a `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY registration_number) row_id
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE registration_number = ?
```

Replace `?` with the registration number that you want to search for.

Another way of getting the `row_id` would be with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE registration_number <= t.registration_number) AS row_id 
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE t.registration_number = ?
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was a great help for me.I have searched almost everything but couldn't get the idea of CTE. That worked so well. :)